# What is an good book to study classical non-equilibrum thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education, non-equilibrium

I am a physics student who has just started my master's program and am taking a course on classical non-equilibrium thermodynamics. I am looking for a book that can help me learn this subject. Are there any online books (kindle, springer,etc.) on this topic?

Comment: what is *non-classical* thermodynamics?

Comment: well, thermodynamics always involves statistics in some form or other, and this also exists as a non-classical theory. Therefore classical, so that there is a distinction to quantum statistics.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/226929/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

So, if by *classical* you mean phenomenological, that is anything non-statistical, then I would suggest the general review book Lavenda: Thermodynamics of irreversible processes, see [here](https://archive.org/details/thermodynamicsof0000lave/page/n5/mode/2up), in which each chapter is one flavor of the subject with many references, the first five chapters is reasonably easy to read, the rest is not so.

But I also urge you to start with three very readable and rightly famous classical papers that "launched" the subject.

(1) Eckart: The Thermodynamics of Irreversible Processes. I. The Simple Fluid
https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.58.267

(2) Bridgman: The Thermodynamics of Plastic Deformation and Generalized Entropy
https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.22.56

(3) Tolman & Fine: On the Irreversible Production of Entropy
https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.20.51